# How to use sql statement Between and like together

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite database in android app and I want to search in (zan) table between 1-100 range in (id) column then withing that range find words similar in (eng) column, but it does not return anything and it does not give error either, thanks.

```
 "Select * from zan where id (between 1 and 100) and eng like '"+smilarkeyword+"&'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be  id between  and the wildchar for like is %  (or _)

```
  "Select * from zan 
  where id between 1 and 100  
  and eng like '%"+smilarkeyword+"%'"
```

where % stands for 0 or more characters and _ stands for exactly one character

Comment: @Rotwang   correct .. answer updated with your comment